# MySQL wrong date calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

First time i see this sql behavior. I don't have any idea how to check or what to do. After new year one of our system started doing strange things. I found this code in our company system

```
SELECT masinu_galiojimai. * , 
       galiojimu_tipai.pavadinimas,
       galiojimu_tipai.ispeti_pries_x_dienu, 
       masinos.masinos_nr AS masina,
       IF( DATEDIFF( masinu_galiojimai.galioja_iki, CURDATE( ) ) <0,  "baigesi", 2 *2 ) AS liko
FROM masinos
LEFT JOIN masinu_galiojimai ON masinu_galiojimai.masinos_id = masinos.id
LEFT JOIN galiojimu_tipai ON masinu_galiojimai.ispejimo_id = galiojimu_tipai.id
```

as you can see its very logical if TRUE it should output word: baigesi and if false it should calculate 2*2 (i changed this by my self to test)
and in result i get that 2*2 is not 4, but 62616967657369. How this even possible? If i try to subtract today date and 2018-12-31 i get not 13 days, but 8880.

Server time working good, no problem. Where do I need to start checking or something?

EDIT: to understand better i include photo. As you can see there is no word: baigese and there is no correct math answer:

[Image attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNk2y.png)

Comment: What is the datatype of `galioja_iki`?

Comment: Just: date, with default value: 0000-00-00

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This system is not our programmed. Our company bough few years ago, i hate by my self, because its running on ubuntu 14 with php 5.2. I cant renew php because it will stop work, they rewrited many functions, disabled all error logging. If i enable error logging i will get about 300 php errors in each page. You can only imagine what the hell they wrote. Many files is encrypted, so basically i cant modify php as much as i want

Comment: what's in the "baigesi" column and what datatype is it?

Comment: Nothing, its just print this word which mean expired. This sql should check if transport validity have expired already or soon will expire and show date (where i put 2*2)

Comment: can you reproduce without reading from the table? It looks like server is corrupt somehow. like just SELECT IF( DATEDIFF( '0000-00-00', CURDATE( ) ) <0,  "expired", 2 *2 );

Comment: Actually, only way this seems possible is if the table has a column named '2'

Comment: Ill attach image: https://imgur.com/a/HEUeHET

Comment: Double checked collums, there is no name such as '2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are "correct" but are displaying as HEX strings instead.

'4' in ASCII is 0x34

'baigesi'
   b  => 62
   a  => 61

etc., so you end up with 62616967657369

This is most likely a configuration of phpmyadmin than anything else, because it is happening after 4 is converted to a string. Try a different client to see what results you get.

Another possibility is the collation settings on the connection. See this bug report
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35211

it seems to be a result of using utf8_bin encoding on the connection protocol.

Comment: I tried Sequel Pro for mac and now i see everything as i should. Thank you this helped. but i have other problem. This code must show two dates: one which transport validity already expired and other where validity will expire soon. If date is possitive number php will show this date, if date is negative for e.g. -13 days, then php wont print anything.

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve your problem, but will give you a clue.

```
ASCII codes in hex: 
0x62 0x61 0x69 0x67 0x65 0x73 0x69
 b    a    i    g    e    s    i
```

So when you get `62616967657369` it's not for `2*2` but instead of `baigesi`.